# How can i call xaml button from mainactivity.cs on xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a project to play a sound. I found out that to play sound I've to use android.media, so I'm trying to shift all my work to mainactivity.cs. The problem I'm facing is I have no idea how to call xaml button from mainactivity.cs. I have read somewhere that we will have to create an interface. But I can't understand from the example provided. So any solution is really appreciated Thanks

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Dependency Service mechanism to call platform specific code on an action. See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/

Otherwise, I suggest you to use a Cross Platform Library to Play your Media easily without having to write specific code: this one is efficient:

https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager

https://blog.xamarin.com/play-audio-and-video-with-the-mediamanager-plugin-for-xamarin/

Comment: Actually i am making piano project with xamarin form (xaml) because my college ask me to use xaml form. I want to make that if i press the button, it will make a tone.. but the tone is taken from my local disk, so i make a button in xaml , and i want to call the button name in mainactivity.cs, can i do that? Any one can give me a help? I really aprreciate it ...thank you

Comment: Have you some code sample with the action you want to perform on Android side? With this, I will give you some code basics to run it on a Xamarin Forms action